# nvoglv32.dll Can't find or open the PDB FILE

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia

i'm trying to learn C++ OpenGl.

now when i started working on shadering my program just wont work and every time i start it i get message saying:

```
Exception thrown at 0x03FA98B0 (nvoglv32.dll) in Inspire.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

and that it cant find the "nvoglv.pbd".
i have all my graphic drivers UP-TO-DATE.

the entire code: https://github.com/Jrp0h/Inspire-Engine

i cant really post all the code here, it would be do long.

Im just following a tutorial and it was at this video in got the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mU80e0eMLjc&index=11&list=PLSPw4ASQYyymu3PfG9gxywSPghnSMiOAW

All help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Typo

Comment: That kind of error means that there's a pointer or function pointer whose value is 0. Use a debugger to look for that pointer.

Comment: Plugin to debug such things for NVidia videocards https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-graphics

Comment: The answer to the pdb location question https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-driver-symbol-server-now-available/

Answer (score 1):

PDB files contain a detailed list of symbols of the particular code module they refer to and often also some source code. `nvoglv*.dll` is the OpenGL implementation of Nvidia, which is closed source. Nvidia driver developers are the *only* people that have access to the PDB files.

Your program crashing in `nvogl32v.dll` does not mean that the problem is located in `nvogl32v.dll`. What is means is, that you passed some invalid pointer into OpenGL or gave it wrong information about the buffer that pointer addresses. When Nvidia's OpenGL driver then subsequently tries to access the buffer, it has to trust your program that the information is correct. If it is not correct, your program crashes.

When that happens you get a backtrace from the debugger (if you run it in a debugger). Ignore every step in the backtrace that's not in your code. Look only at your code, that's where the problem is.

Comment: `Look only at your code, that's where the problem is.` Not necessarily. I think this can also happen when the memory gets too fragmented. In my application I have the same crash occur when the application ran for a very long time (it's a 32 bit application), at which memory fragmentation becomes an issue. The game creates and destroys thousands of VBOs.

Comment: @Tara: Memory fragmentation does not cause access violations / segmentation faults. Period, no discussion. What memory fragmentation *does* cause is that memory allocation may fail. And if you attempt memory allocation without testing if it succeeded, then that's a bug. And I'd be very surprised drivers don't check if memory allocation failed.

Comment: Of course it doesn't cause access violations or segmentation faults on its own, but if you don't check for failed allocations, you introduce access violations. I ran into the case where when my engine was running for a very long time (lots of GPU resource allocations and deallocations), allocation of big textures would fail (inside of OpenGL). I was still able to create smaller textures, but bigger textures would fail. I was able to allocate the big textures just fine when the engine was freshly started. From what I could tell, there were no GPU memory leaks either.

Comment: However, I am still trying to get to the source of this by trying out different allocation strategies.

Comment: Alright. I did some more testing a while ago and these are the messages I got from the driver itself (Nvidia driver version 436.30): `Debug message (0): Unknown internal debug message. The NVIDIA OpenGL driver has encountered an out of memory error. This application might behave inconsistently and fail.` and `Debug message (1285): GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY error generated. Failed to allocate CPU address space mapping for texture (consider building 64-bit app).`.

Comment: @Tara: Out of curiosity: Are you allocating a "fresh" buffer object for each and every piece of geometry you want to draw? If so, then *don't do that!* Buffer objects are meant to be used for rarely reallocated memory pools.

Comment: I don't think the way the VBOs are used is relevant here (they are also the smallest memory consumer in the scene). The test I ran reloads a few scenes over and over again (which loads and unloads resources). It's not a real world use case (on purpose). It's the CPU memory fragmentation which makes the memory *uploads* to the driver fail (just like the 2nd driver error message says), not the VRAM allocation. The driver is free to defragment the VRAM. My assumption is that the part of the driver that lives in the host application suffers from the host's memory fragmentation too.